# WPF Bind to an attached property somewhere up in the visual tree

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have an attached property `ZoneBackground`. This can be noted on any framework element.

I now have a style `ZonedTextBox`. This should apply the value of `ZoneBackground` to a textbox. The clue is: The style does not know where in the visual hierachy `ZoneBackground` is noted and on which element.

Is it possible to search for the first parent which has a value for `ZoneBackground` and use that value?

I got this XAML:

```
<Grid controls:ZoneStylingBehavior.ZoneBackground="Red">
    ...
    <TextBox Background="{Binding controls:ZoneStylingBehavior.ZoneBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}" />
    ...
</Grid>
```

This does not work and I would further more like to be able to note `ZoneBackground` anywhere in the visual tree like on `StackPanel`, `Grid` and maybe multiple times.

---

**Update**: As suggested I tried it with dp inheritance. That idea sounds great but I was not yet able to succeed.

The DP declaration:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ZoneBackgroundProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ZoneBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(ZoneStylingBehavior), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
```

The XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid controls:ZoneStylingBehavior.ZoneBackground="{StaticResource BrushGreen}">
         ...
         <Label Background="{Binding controls:ZoneStylingBehavior.ZoneBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" Content="test" />
         ...
    </Grid>
    ...
    <Grid controls:ZoneStylingBehavior.ZoneBackground="{StaticResource BrushRed}">
        ...
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

The console outputs:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'controls:ZoneStylingBehavior' property not found on 'object' ''TextBox' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=controls:ZoneStylingBehavior.ZoneBackground; DataItem='TextBox' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

The binding trace on level `High` shows:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=17086942) for Binding (hash=33055417)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'controls:ZoneStylingBehavior.ZoneBackground'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=17086942): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=17086942): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=17086942): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.Label.Background (hash=18524697)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=17086942): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=17086942): Found data context element: <null> (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 72 :   RelativeSource.Self found Label (hash=18524697)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=17086942): Activate with root item Label (hash=18524697)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=17086942):   At level 0 - for Label.controls:ZoneStylingBehavior found accessor <null>
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'controls:ZoneStylingBehavior' property not found on 'object' ''Label' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=controls:ZoneStylingBehavior.ZoneBackground; DataItem='Label' (Name=''); target element is 'Label' (Name=''); target property is 'Background' (type 'Brush')
System.Windows.Data Warning: 103 : BindingExpression (hash=17086942): Replace item at level 1 with {NullDataItem}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=17086942): TransferValue - got raw value {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 88 : BindingExpression (hash=17086942): TransferValue - using fallback/default value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=17086942): TransferValue - using final value <null>
```

Can someone point out what's wrong?

Comment: what about making the ZoneBackground and inherited property, then you would only have to do something like 
    <TextBox Background="{Binding controls:ZoneStylingBehavior.ZoneBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}" />

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of searching first parent in Visual tree where this value is set, make the attached property to **`inherit by default`** by setting **`FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits`** flag for attached property while registering it.

Sample:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ZoneBackgroundProperty =
         DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ZoneBackground",
                                      typeof(Brush), typeof(ZoneStylingBehavior),
       new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
```

So, this way it will automatically inherit value from its first parent in Visual tree with value set for attached property. *(DataContext DP also works like this)*

***UPDATE***:

For attached property binding you need to wrap binding in parenthesis.

```
<Label Background="{Binding (controls:ZoneStylingBehavior.ZoneBackground), 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
       Content="test"/>
```

Comment: That looks like a great idea: Unfortunately I could not get it to work. Maybe I am missing a small detail. I updated the question.

Comment: @ZoolWay - See the update in answer for your follow up question.

Comment: Oh, did not notice that! Thanks for pointing me this syntax issue too! :)